# Amazon RDS database free tier storage limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I wanted to use the free tier of RDS, but when I create instance, I was able to create one with 2000 GB (minimum 5GB, maximum 3072GB). But shouldn't the free RDS be only 20GB allowed? I've successfully created it and I'm very worried if I'll be charged for it.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: According to the pricing page, you will be charged for provisioned, not just used, storage, so very likely you'll be charged if you go over your free quota.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  so it's safer if I create one that only has 20GB storage space right? Because it can never go beyond the limit that way.

Comment: You're already over the limit by provisioning 2000GB, if you use 20GB you'll still be paying for 2000. The only way to not pay is to provision 20GB or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free tier works as a billing discount on certain services. You will be billed for any services used beyond the free tier discounts.

Comment: thank you! so it should be safe if I create one that only has 20GB storage space right? Because it can never go beyond the limit that way.

Comment: Correct. However, depending on how long you had the instance with 2000GB of storage you may be billed a bit for that. Usually storage is prorated to the hour. You will only be charged for the hours you have it provisioned. If it stays below the free tier discount, you wont be charged anything.